# Find equivalent of recurrent sequence $u_1=1$, $u_{n+1}=1+\frac n {u_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is defined:
$$u_1=1, u_{n+1}=1+\dfrac n {u_n}$$

The question asks to find an asymptotic development of 2 terms for $n\to+\infty$. I have got $u_n\sim_\infty\sqrt{n} $, but how to derive the 2nd term?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_{n}=\sqrt{n}+a+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left( \dfrac{1}{n} \right)$, then

\begin{align*}
  u_{n+1} &\sim 1+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+a+\frac{b}{\sqrt{n}}} \\
  \sqrt{n+1}+a+\frac{b}{\sqrt{n+1}} &\sim
  1+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+a+\frac{b}{\sqrt{n}}} \\
  \sqrt{n}+a+\frac{b+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{n}} &\sim
  \sqrt{n}+(1-a)+\frac{a^2-b}{\sqrt{n}} \\
\end{align*}

Equating corresponding orders:

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    a &= 1-a \\
    b+\frac{1}{2} &= a^2-b
  \end{align*}
\right. \implies (a,b)=\left( \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{8} \right)$$

Comment: But why the power differs by 1/2 every time?

Comment: You've got $u_{n}\sim \sqrt{n}$, right?  So $u_{n+1} \sim 1+\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}+O(1)$.  It's natural to try the orders of every halves.

Comment: This approach can prove nothing, at most it can help to check that if such an expansion holds then its coefficients are such and such. What about attacking the question itself?